# natsClient.Subscribe("some_subject", some_callback): Does the 'some_callback' callback run in its own subroutine in Golang?

Tags: go, messaging, nats.io

Essentially what the subject says. I'm interested to know whether each time the callback method is invoked the nats-lib for golang ensures that the callback will run on its very own goroutine (I'm 99% sure that it does but I need to make sure because I can't find any explicit piece of documentation in nats that conclusively states it so - feel free to copy paste any links if I've missed something).

If the callback does indeed run in it's own goroutine I'm also interested to know whether:

a. the same goroutine is used every time for a specific subscription

or b. an ephimeral goroutine is created for each firing of the callback: in this case the goroutine gets disposed of after the callback has done its work

Comment: NATS comes with the source code; what is the problem to just look and see for yourself?

Comment: That's a fair and perfectly valid point @kostix Considering I'm relatively new to golang I believe it would be error-prone on my behalf to venture into the source-code and draw the wrong conclusions - I'll probably be deep diving into libs once I feel more confident. For now an equally valid approach would be to place the question here for the sake of future reference while enjoying the benefits of public visibility and peer-review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `conn.Subscribe("some_subject", someCallback)`, it executes this piece of code if the callback is defined:

```
// If we have an async callback, start up a sub specific
    // Go routine to deliver the messages.
    if cb != nil {
        sub.typ = AsyncSubscription
        sub.pCond = sync.NewCond(&sub.mu)
        go nc.waitForMsgs(sub)
    }
```

It launches a goroutine for the created subscription. When a message arrives, it executes the defined callback inside the `waitForMsgs` goroutine.

In short, the answer is a., it uses the same goroutine every time for a specific subscription.